# Shouldn't we keep track of the offset when we write to an OutputStream?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, outputstream

The `read()` method inside `copyFile()` reads `buf.length` bytes from the input stream and then it writes them to the output stream from the start until `len`.

```
public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);

        }
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If we always writing to the output stream from the start **isn't the data of the previous iteration overwritten**?

Don't we need to keep track of the offset? For example if the first iteration wrote 1024 bytes then the second iteration should write `out.write(buf,1024,len);`.

Comment: The start is the start of the array, not of the stream. The data is in fact appended to the previous one each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Arnaud commented

> The start is the start of the array, not of the stream. The data is in
>   fact appended to the previous one each time.

I was not careful quick scanning the docs and from *"Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this output stream"*, I got the point that `off` was the offset of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the `buf` is a buffer and not the entire data stream.

Also, you are using `public int read(byte[] b)` method which means which it is same  as `read(b, 0, b.length)`. So the buffer shall be pointing to next buf.length values of the data.

For more information, please check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[]) .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My query was about write() but it's ok it's being answered in the comments.